# Passing data through onPress doesn't allow to pass parameter in a function properly

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to pass data to a specific page in react native. Whenever i press a button to go to that page, the function which is supposed to be called on that specific page on specific event is called earlier when i'm pressing the button.

```js
add=(ss)=> {
     const textInput = this.state.textInput.concat(TextInput)
     this.setState({ textInput })

    console.log(ss)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
        <List>
            <ListItem>
              <Left>
                <Text style={styles.firstText}>Address : <Text>{this.state.address}</Text></Text>
              </Left>
              <Right>
                <Icon name="create" onPress={this.add('dssda')}></Icon>
              </Right>
            </ListItem></List>
```

This add function is being called when i'm pressing button to go to this page. But i want it to be called when i click the icon on this page.

Comment: I think you have provided incomplete code..also try onPress={() => this.add('dssda')}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the function properly, you should write it like below:

```
onPress ={() => this.add('dssda')}
```

If you would not wanting to pass parameters and you would have written `onPress={this.add}` then the function would have properly called on the onPress event only as it is properly binded there with same number of params as that from the callback of `onPress` i.e. no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

On Press should be binded,

```
onPress ={() => this.add(data)}
```

Which is passed to ss variable in your method,

```
add=(ss)=> {
     const textInput = this.state.textInput.concat(TextInput)
     this.setState({ textInput })

    console.log(ss)
  }
```

Hope this works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to bind your function. You can bind event in constructor of Class Component like this:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
}
```